# Cannot find path because it doesn't exist

Tags: powershell

I have written the below PowerShell script to do a remote Office uninstall.

```
$computers = @("WGBCZC4253TQY")

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    Copy-Item -Force -Recurse -Verbose -Path \\sgblon340012\O365\Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls -Destination \\$computer\C$\temp200718\

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
        & { 
            Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Force -Verbose
            cd C:\temp200718\Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls -Verbose
            . .\Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls.ps1
            Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls
            Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Force -Verbose
        }
    }

    Remove-Item -Force -Recurse \\$computer\C$\temp200718 -Verbose
}
```

but it generates the below errors about the path not existing even though you can clearly see that it does exist as the files have just been copied!

```
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Copy Directory" on target "Item: \\sgblon340012\O365\Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls Destination: \\WGBCZC4253TQY\C$\temp200718\".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: \\WGBCZC4253TQY\C$\temp200718\".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: \\sgblon340012\O365\Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls\OffScrub03.vbs Destination: \\WGBCZC4253TQY\C$\temp200718\OffScrub03.vbs".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: \\sgblon340012\O365\Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls\OffScrub07.vbs Destination: \\WGBCZC4253TQY\C$\temp200718\OffScrub07.vbs".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: \\sgblon340012\O365\Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls\OffScrub10.vbs Destination: \\WGBCZC4253TQY\C$\temp200718\OffScrub10.vbs".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: \\sgblon340012\O365\Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls\OffScrubc2r.vbs Destination: \\WGBCZC4253TQY\C$\temp200718\OffScrubc2r.vbs".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: \\sgblon340012\O365\Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls\OffScrub_O15msi.vbs Destination: \\WGBCZC4253TQY\C$\temp200718\OffScrub_O15msi.vbs". VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: \\sgblon340012\O365\Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls\OffScrub_O16msi.vbs Destination: \\WGBCZC4253TQY\C$\temp200718\ OffScrub_O16msi.vbs".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: \\sgblon340012\O365\Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls\README.md Destination: \\WGBCZC4253TQY\C$\temp200718\README.md".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: \\sgblon340012\O365\Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls\README_Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls.md Destination: \\WGBCZC4253TQY\C$\temp200718\README_Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls.md".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: \\sgblon340012\O365\Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls\Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls.ps1 Destination: \\WGBCZC4253TQY\C$\temp200718\Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls.ps1".
VERBOSE: Performing operation "Set-ExecutionPolicy" on Target "Bypass". Cannot find path 'C:\temp200718\Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls' because it does not exist.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\temp200718\R...sOfficeInstalls:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
    + PSComputerName        : WGBCZC4253TQY   The term '.\Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or  if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
    + PSComputerName        : WGBCZC4253TQY   The term 'Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a  path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
    + PSComputerName        : WGBCZC4253TQY   VERBOSE: Performing operation "Set-ExecutionPolicy" on Target "Bypass".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target "\\WGBCZC4253TQY\C$\temp200718".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "\\WGBCZC4253TQY\C$\temp200718\OffScrub03.vbs".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "\\WGBCZC4253TQY\C$\temp200718\OffScrub07.vbs".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "\\WGBCZC4253TQY\C$\temp200718\OffScrub10.vbs". VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "\\WGBCZC4253TQY\C$\temp200718\OffScrubc2r.vbs".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "\\WGBCZC4253TQY\C$\temp200718\OffScrub_O15msi.vbs".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "\\WGBCZC4253TQY\C$\temp200718\OffScrub_O16msi.vbs".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "\\WGBCZC4253TQY\C$\temp200718\README.md". VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "\\WGBCZC4253TQY\C$\temp200718\README_Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls.md".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "\\WGBCZC4253TQY\C$\temp200718\Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls.ps1".
```

Comment: I am confused on what you are doing here, but it seems that the error comes from the folder `C:\temp200718\Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls` as I see the files are copied to the new destination. Then the ps1 script `remove-previousofficeinstalls` probably is not in that path maybe you should put a full path or something that the script can be located and not `.\` As a sidenote, please don't put the execution policy to Bypass.

Comment: Quote your paths. `Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls` is now used as part of the path (as string), as name of the .ps1 file and is also the name of your function to perform.. It's the `cd C:\temp200718\Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls` command that is failing here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a PowerShell gotcha. If you copy a folder to a non-existing destination folder, PowerShell will create the destination folder and then copy the *content* of the source folder. If you want the entire source folder copied to the destination folder, make sure the destination folder already exists:

```cs
$src = '\\sgblon340012\O365\Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls'
$dst = "\\${computer}\C$\temp200718"
if (-not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $dst)) {
    New-Item -Type Directory -Path $dst | Out-Null
}
Copy-Item -Path $src -Destination "${dst}\" -Force -Recurse -Verbose
```

Alternatively you could specify the full destination path:

```cs
$src = '\\sgblon340012\O365\Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls'
$dst = "\\${computer}\C$\temp200718\Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls"
Copy-Item -Path $src -Destination "${dst}\" -Force -Recurse -Verbose
```

However, should that destination folder already exist for some reason the command will copy the entire source folder to the destination folder, thus creating a path `\\${computer}\C$\temp200718\Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls\Remove-PreviousOfficeInstalls\`. Hence I don't recommend going this route. Stick with the first example.